# Kivy no muestra texto de etiquetas en Windows

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.7

Estoy intentando usar kivy sobre windows, ya antes comencé con él en MacOS y los pocos ejemplos y ejercicios van bien, ahora intente correrlos en windows 7 y 10 y el famoso 'Hello World!' no aparece en la ventana, solo carga una ventana con el nombre del proyecto y un fondo negro pero no aparece ningún texto. estoy usando la version de kivy 1.10.1 y python 3.7.0, este es el código y una imagen de lo que muestra:

```
#File name: hello.py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
class HelloApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label (text='Hello World')

if __name__== "__main__":
    HelloApp().run()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Juan, añade siempre la etiqueta principal del lenguaje a tus preguntas, entre otras cosa hace bastante más visibles tus preguntas. No se si lo has solucionado, pero ¿Qué te muestra la consola? El código es correcto, podría ser algún problema con alguna dependencia.

Comment: tambien me pasaba el problema lo tenia con el MainApp o en tu caso HelloApp, seguro hay un hello.kv que confunde al programa

Comment: El unico error que veo es que estas retornando la clase Label, no una instancia. El paréntesis esta separado por un espacio. solo júntalo

Answer (score -1):

Aqui en Linux Mint, probe tu programa. Inicialmente me saco un mensaje de error, pero era sobre la version de Kivy:
kivy.require('1.10.1')

Cambie la linea por: kivy.require('1.9.1') que era la version que tenia instalada y funciono

Comment: La pregunta dice **explícitamente** `en Windows`. Lo que haga o deje de hacer en Linux no es relevante.

Comment: PERDON....NO OPINARE MAS, SI SON TAN CERRADOS

Comment: Ni cerrados ni abiertos: `¿ Cuanto es 2 + 2 ? No no, en noruego no se usan esos números`. No pregunto por cómo se escribe en Noruega, pregunto cuánto es `2 + 2`.